# downloading do not turn off target

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

the mobile in a screen appear and green android and downloading do not turn off target and don't exit from this mode

what should I do

Comment: It would help if you'd describe how you got into that situation. Without a little background, all we can do is guess-work – which might get you into even more trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you mean [Odin (Download) mode](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=odin+mode&safe=strict&biw=1366&bih=662&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXm-je79XRAhUC62MKHT72CsUQ_AUIBigB):

[image]

Force power off the phone (usually by holding POWER) and then power it back on. If it won't, you probably need to flash a factory image.